# "last year" vs. "the last / whole of the last year" vs. "whole the last year"

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I would have question related to other question I asked today.
I know that:

- **last year** refers to something that happens in the last year (which could be yesterday if today is 1.1.)
- **the last year** — means the last 365 days including today.

But what about "for the whole of the last year" and "for the whole of last year"? In an answer I received it is mentioned that this "of" disctincts between last year and last 12 months, which I thought is done by "the"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either the *the* or the *of* would make a difference.  Concerning *the*: *For the whole of last year* means all of the preceding calendar year, whereas *for the whole of the last year* means all of the preceding 365 (or 366, in this case) days.

*For the whole the last year* is ungrammatical, and *for the whole last year* sounds quite colloquial, though it's not incorrect.  I can see *the whole last year* meaning either the last calendar year or the last 365/366 days, though I would say that it's more generally used to refer to the last 365/366 days.

Comment: Thank you, also this is not correct? "I have been working at XYZ for the whole last year"

Comment: My answer addresses that.

Comment: If you want to refer to the time period beginning 365 days ago and crossing calendar year boundaries, you are probably better to say "for the past year" or "for a year". That would eliminate the possible ambiguity.